# onClick function in Chart.js passing the selected object, Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

There is onClick function in Chart.js documentation, http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-common-chart-configuration
it got called everytime an click on chart occurs, it looks like this:

```
options: {
    onClick: this.Function
  }

Function(event, array){
...
}
```

But then it is passing the entire context and how can I know which specific part of the chart got clicked?

Answer (score 4):

I have found the answer:

```
options: {
   onClick: this.Function.bind(this),
}

Function(event, array) {
   let clickedElement = this.doughnutChart.getElementAtEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this**

```
import { ChartEvent } from 'chart.js'

options: {
  onClick: this.Function
}

Function(evt: ChartEvent, i: []) {
...
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).